# Jupyter notebook won't start - despite various fixes

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Every time I try to run jupyter notebook (using the command `python -m jupyter notebook` it returns:

```
Jupyter command "jupyter-notebook" not found.
```

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling jupyter, I've tried this rec:

uninstall pyzmq and install it again.

Then I ran pip3 install --upgrade nbconvert.

I also did pip install --upgrade pywin32==224

from a different question. again no dice, still the same return. I definitely have notebook installed, I've done `jupyter --version` and it returned that I have notebook installed.

I did `python -m jupyter --debug --paths` which returned:

```
JUPYTER_PREFER_ENV_PATH is not set, making the user-level path preferred over the environment-level path for data and config
JUPYTER_NO_CONFIG is not set, so we use the full path list for config
JUPYTER_CONFIG_PATH is not set, so we do not prepend anything to the config paths
JUPYTER_CONFIG_DIR is not set, so we use the default user-level config directory
Python's site.ENABLE_USER_SITE is True, so we add the user site directory 'C:\Users\Nathaniel Paczek\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-pac
kages'
JUPYTER_PATH is not set, so we do not prepend anything to the data paths
JUPYTER_DATA_DIR is not set, so we use the default user-level data directory
JUPYTER_RUNTIME_DIR is not set, so we use the default runtime directory

config:
    C:\Users\Nathaniel Paczek\.jupyter
    C:\Users\Nathaniel Paczek\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\etc\jupyter
    C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\etc\jupyter
    C:\ProgramData\jupyter
data:
    C:\Users\Nathaniel Paczek\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\Roaming\jupyter
    C:\Users\Nathaniel Paczek\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\share\jupyter
    C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\share\jupyter
    C:\ProgramData\jupyter
runtime:
    C:\Users\Nathaniel Paczek\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\Roaming\jupyter\runtime
```

i realise this is a lengthy question but I'm tearing my hair out trying to get it sorted so would really appreciate any help that can be offered.

Comment: You say you uninstalled and reinstalled, but how? There's a lot of ways you could have done that and you could be mixing and matching and digging yourself a deeper hole.  I'd suggest using [the Anaconda distribution](https://www.anaconda.com/products/distribution). Jupyter will get installed with it. Then you open the Anaconda navigator and launch it from in there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the `notebook` package - see [the Jupyter documentation](https://jupyter.org/install#jupyter-notebook).